Qt console application ignores inputs (cin)
I just installed Qt Creator 13.0.2 and created my first console application (left all in default):
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>

void do_qt(){
    QTextStream qin(stdin);
    QTextStream qout(stdout);

    qout << "Please enter your name: ";
    QString name = qin.readLine();
    qout << "Hello " << name;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    do_qt();
    
    return a.exec();
}

When I run the application, this is what I get in the application output
21:41:39: Démarrage de C:\DEV\Qt\core_tuto\qt6-e3\qt6-e3\build\Desktop_Qt_6_7_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\qt6-e3.exe…
Please enter your name: Hello

It seems like the readLine() line is skipped.
Kit selection window (I left it in default):


I changed the option "Default for "Run in terminal"" to enabled (under edit->preferences->Build & Run):

Then, when I run the application, it starts blank (with no text displayed) in the terminal (in the bottom of the IDE). When I put a random string, it shows up in the second line like this:

xoxo Please enter your name: Hello xoxo



See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484950/using-cin-in-qtcreator

QCoreApplication isn't just for hanging it on the wall and be pretty. exec() is actually what handles the events

Side note: QtCreator is not a requirement for writing Qt applications and it can also be used for writing non-Qt applications.

Please use the answer box to add an answer, don't add it to the question.

Make sure you're running program in terminal. The Output window doesn't provide input stream capability so reading from stdin would silently fail. And for this particular scenario a qin.flush(); call might be required before using the streams.

I changed the oprion "Default for "Run in terminal"" to enabled (under edit->preferences->Build & Run), than when I run the application it starts blank (with no text displayed) in the Terminal (in the bottom of the IDE) . when i put a random string it shows up in the second line like this:
xoxo
Please enter your name: Hello xoxo

@Batman when you generate output you need to flush it.  Most commonly that's done by outputting a newline, which is detected by the runtime and automatically causes a flush.  In this case you don't have a newline so you need to flush it yourself.
